# Button to play a movie within a movie in ActionScript 3 Presentation

Tags: actionscript-3, button, movieclip

I am making a Flash Presentation, so each animation is within a movie clip (movie_mc). This movie clip has a key frame holding each animation (4 keyframes/animated slides). The first movie instance/slide is called "slide1871". I labeled the first frame within this movie "slide1871". My buttons are on the main timeline.

I CANNOT get the code to work to link to play the first frame of movie slide1871 (within movie_mc). It either doesn't work at all, or it plays the 4 keyframes of the 4 slides I have within movie_mc.

This plays the 4 keyframes:

```
    btn1871.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1);

    function btn1(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        movie_mc.gotoAndPlay("slide1871");
    }
```

I've tried a bunch of other stuff that the button doesn't even work.
Please help, hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: So your hierarchy looks like this:  MainTimeline -> movie_mc -> slide1871 -> (frame labeled "1871") ?

Comment: Your code is telling the movie_mc clip to go to a frame on it's own timeline called "slide1871".   Sounds to me like what you wants is `movie_mc.slide1871.play();`  Share your .fla and someone here can give you a definite answer.

Comment: Correct, that is the hierarchy. That still just plays the 4 keyframes of movie_mc, instead of going into the first keyframe and playing movie instance "slide1871".

Comment: I've tried putting stops on there too.

Comment: Do each of your 4 keyframes have a `stop();` command on them?

Comment: it would be very helpful to see you.fla, or at least a screen shot of the movie_mc timeline, and the slide1871 timeline

Comment: I'm not sure how to put up my flash file, or a screenshot. I did move my buttons into the movie_mc with code:
       
        btn1871.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1);
        function btn1(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
         slide1871.gotoAndPlay("slide1871");
        }

AND, it works when it's playing in it's own movie, but once the slider goes on to slide 2 (keyframe 2 -with the second animation) it gives me the error:

        TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at MC_fla::SlidesMovieClip_2/btn1()

Comment: use skydrive or dropbox or box.net or google drive.   StackExchange will let you upload photos and put them directly in your questions/answers