# null object error - button trying to play child movie

Tags: actionscript-3, button

Have a button that needs to play a movie within a movie.

```
btn1871.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);
function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
slides_mc.slide1871.gotoAndPlay("slide1871");
}
```

And I get:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at MC_fla::MainTimeline/fl_MouseClickHandler_2()
```

and idea? thx.

Comment: either `slides_mc` is null, or `slides_mc.slide1871` is null. make sure your instance names are set correctly.

Comment: I don't really see how this question is different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531900/button-to-play-a-movie-within-a-movie-in-actionscript-3-presentation

Comment: Looking for same end result, but set up completely different. Instance names are correct. 

If the presentation is at a point where it's playing within slide1871, the gotoAndPlay works. If it's in a different movie, it's null.

Comment: It's null if you put the code in a different MovieClip because you're not in the same scope as `slides_mc` anymore.

Comment: the code is on the main timeline, playing keyframe slide 1 (slide1871) then keyframe slide 2 (slide 1903).. when it's on each respective mc, that button works to start over the movie. If it's in a different mc it's null. What do I do to not make it null?

Comment: Your code is sending the 'play head' to a LABEL called 'slide1871' in a MovieClip called 'slide1871' inside a MovieClip called 'slides_mc'. I only ask because there seems to be some ambiguity to your question, but are you sure this is what you want to do? Have you got a 'slide1871' label inside your 'slide1871' MoveClip?

Comment: Yes. absolutely correct.

Comment: Again, you need to share your .fla.   Just use one of the many could file sharing services:   skydrive/dropbox/box.net/googledrive etc.